# How to split string a value and parse it to int in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, split

I have something like this:

```
idsList = '1,23,46,67,82'
```

These are my parameters value which will be passed to my stored procedure, these are string values.

I want to use it something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (id_list)
```

- `id` is of type `int`

while

- `idsList` is `nvarchar` (string)

How do I split the values of `idsList` and parse it to Int value then put it to my query?

Please for SQL Server only.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mssql+split+string&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=BP6DVcyEEKW7ygOFhrjgBg) it for you. Have a look at first result.

Comment: Depending on the client your using passing in a *table valued param* will negate the need for this entirely.

Comment: Similar question often asked in stackoverflow.com. ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380003/get-data-from-comma-separated-string-input I think, it will work.

Comment: If you can't use a table valued parameter, and must split strings in sql server, then read [this article.](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)